# Scrapy - Use proxy middleware but disable proxy for specific requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, screen-scraping, scrapy

I want to use proxy middleware in my Scrapy but not every request needs a proxy. I don't want to abuse the proxy usage and make the proxy prone to get banned.

Is there a way for me to disable proxy in some requests when the proxy middleware is turned on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can add `dont_proxy` meta and sets it to true on the requests

```
yield scrapy.Request(
    url, 
    meta={"dont_proxy": True}, 
    callback=self.parse
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's in the [docs](http://scrapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#module-scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy).

You can set the meta key `proxy` per-request, to a value like `http://some_proxy_server:port`.

Comment: I kind of feel comfortable using middleware, and I want to make an exception on the middleware usage. The middleware plays a big role here